# Is it possible to detect whether a local variable declared?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to detect whether a local variable declared?

The reason is that I'd like to have a macro (`LOG`), which has a logic like this:

```
if (<logContext is declared>) {
    log(logContext, <parameters>);
} else {
    DefaultLogContext logContext(*this);
    log(logContext, <parameters>);
}
```

So, if the macro sees that there is a local variable named `logContext`, then it passes this variable to `log`. If `logContext` doesn't exist, then it creates a default `logContext`, and passes that to `log`.

Note: `DefaultLogContext` is a dependent type. It means that this logging macro can only be used in a class member function, and this type is a typedef to an actual type-dependent `LogContext` class:

```
class File {
    typedef FileLogContext DefaultLogContext;

    void open() {
        LOG("open"); // here, I'd like LOG to create a new local logContext
    }

    void complexFunction() {
        FileLogContext logContext(...);
        logContext.setup();

        LOG("pass1"); // here, I'd like LOG to use my declared logContext
        pass1();

        LOG("pass2"); // same comment as at pass1
        pass2();

        // other LOG and pass function calls here
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to accept `log_context` explicitly?

Comment: Any reason why you don't do `log << context << thing to log` and then your log object can hold a default context if not provided?  (Aside:  "I'd like to have a macro" is often the sign that eyebrows should be raised)

Comment: @VTT: No. I'd like to make things automatic. I use this logContext all over the place currently, and the pattern is clear. It could be automatic, and with it, logging can be made easier. There is absolutely no point that the programmer needs to specify this always.

Comment: @UKMonkey: as you see, the default log context is dependent on the class, and its members (`*this` is passed to its constructor). It cannot be part of the log object.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::optional`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat ugly solution that checks for a presence of local variable named `local_context`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr class t_Decoy{} const local_context; // should be declared in global scope
class t_Context{};

#define LOG(text) \
[&](char const * const psz_text) -> void \
{ \
  if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<t_Context, decltype(local_context)>) \
  { \ // we can use captured local_context here
     ::std::cout << psz_text << " has local_context" << ::std::endl; \
  } \
  else \
  { \ // we can create default context using captured this
     ::std::cout << psz_text << " no local_context" << ::std::endl; \
  }\
}(text)

int main()
{
    LOG("first");
    t_Context local_context{};
    LOG("second");
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cJwh7Sq3Np2HFKQC)

Comment: Nice trick! I don't really like the global decoy variable, but if that's the only way to do this, I may accept it :) Now I'm thinking about doing the same, but with a type instead. I mean, somehow differentiate between a global `local_context` type vs. local `local_context` variable. This way I don't have to define a global variable. I'm not sure that's possible...

Comment: @geza As an alternative you can define `local_context` as a global function (without implementation).

Comment: It seems that this solution works for me. I've just added a simple modification: I've put `local_context` into its own `Decoy` namespace, and used `using namespace Decoy;` in the macro. This way the solution works everywhere, it doesn't matter in which namespace `LOG` is used (and avoided polluting the global namespace with the decoy). Nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. Without reflection you cannot do such a thing autonomously. Then again, it would be of little benefit here.

Instead you should simply restructure your macros. *You* know, as the programmer, whether a variable is in scope at the point where you write your macro, and can instead use a *different* macro that does not require an extant variable.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this via local variables. If you need an RAII style scoped logging facility, you have no choice but to create a local object explicitly.

```
LogScope logscope("some log msg");
```

If you don't need RAII, then you could have a global log object that maps `__FUNCTION__` (or so) to a log context.

```
#define LOG(msg) { \
    auto& logScope = g_logManager[__FUNCTION__]; \
  }
```