# Is it possible to change behavior of function based on scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I would like to create something similar to rust [unsafe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/working-with-unsafe.html) scope in C++.
The idea is that I have some functions performing number of checks. For example:

```
void check() {
     if (...)
        throw exception(...);

}

void foo() {
     check();

     // do some work
}
```

Now, I want to be able to call function foo() with or (in different context) without performing those checks. Ideally it would look like this:

```
foo(); // call foo and perform checks
unsafe {
    foo(); // call foo without checks
}
```

My question is, is it possible to achieve something like this in compile time? Is it possible to somehow check (or act differently) from `check` function in what scope it is called?

I came up only with a runtime solution: to wrap it in some lambda:

```
unsafe([&] {
    foo();
});
```

where unsafe is implemented as follows:

```
void unsafe(std::function<void()> f)
{
     thread_local_flag = unsafe;
     f();
     thread_local_flag = safe;
}
```

check() function would just check for the thread_local flag and perform checks only when it is set to `safe`.

Comment: Probably related [Is it possible to detect whether a local variable declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263260/is-it-possible-to-detect-whether-a-local-variable-declared/53263503)

Comment: It's similar but, in my case check() function is defined in some other place and would not have access to variables declared when using `unsafe`

Comment: Why not just use two versions of `foo`? The unsafe version could be an overload, a different template instance, or simply depend on a parameter.

Comment: Well, in the example I presented I could do that, but in general, I can call some other function `bar` inside `unsafe` which in turn calls `foo`. And I don't want to specialize `bar` and possible other methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
namespace detail_unsafe {
    thread_local int current_depth;

    struct unsafe_guard {
        unsafe_guard()  { ++current_depth; }
        ~unsafe_guard() { --current_depth; }

        unsafe_guard(unsafe_guard const &) = delete;
        unsafe_guard &operator = (unsafe_guard const &) = delete;
    };
}

#define unsafe \
    if(::detail_unsafe::unsafe_guard _ug; false) {} else

bool currently_unsafe() {
    return detail_unsafe::current_depth > 0;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3001aa50d2a49888). Also, please don't actually define `unsafe` as a macro...

Comment: *'My question is, is it possible to achieve something like this in compile time?'* Just be aware that this still is a runtime solution (@Igor).

Comment: @Aconcagua I *really* should take more time to read questions... Anyway, I don't think this is possible at compile time in the general case, because multiple TUs can be involved and communication between TUs at compile-time is severely restricted...

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to achieve something like this in compile time?

Not the way you presented. Making foo a template function might give you equivalent results, though:

```
enum class CallType // find a better name yourself...
{
    SAFE,
    UNSAFE,
};

template <CallType Type = CallType::SAFE>
void foo()
{
    if constexpr(Type != CallType::UNSAFE)
    {
        if (...)
            throw ...;
    }
    // do some work
}
```

You might call it like:

```
foo();
foo<CallType::UNSAFE>();
```

Disliking templates?

Simple approach (thanks, @[VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt)):

```
void check(); // no template any more

void foo_unsafe()
{
    // do some work
}
inline void foo()
{
    check();
    foo_unsafe();
}
```

Or selecting via parameter (this pattern exists in standard library, too):

```
struct Unsafe
{
};
inline Unsafe unsafe;

void check();

void foo(Unsafe)
{
    // do some work
}
inline void foo()
{
    check();
    foo(unsafe);
}
```

*Edit:*

> Well, in the example I presented I could do that, but in general, I can call some other function bar inside unsafe which in turn calls foo. And I don't want to specialize bar and possible other methods.

Unter this constraint, the template variant might be the closest you can get to at *compile* time; you don't have to *specialise* all the functions, but you'd need to make templates from:

```
template <CallType Type = CallType::SAFE>
void bar()
{
    // do some other work
    foo<Type>(); // just call with template parameter
    // yet some further work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a RAII type to toggle the unsafe flag inside a scope as such:

```
thread_local bool unsafe_flag = false;

/// RAII Type that toggles the flag on while it's alive
/// Possibly add a reference counter so it can be used nested
struct unsafe_scope
{
    constexpr unsafe_scope() { unsafe_flag = true; }
    ~unsafe_scope()          { unsafe_flag = false; }
};

/// Gets a value from a pointer
int get_value(int* ptr)
{
    if ( unsafe_flag )
    {
        if ( ptr == nullptr ) { return 0; }
    }

    return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int* x = nullptr;

    //return get_value(x); // Doesn't perform the check

    {
        unsafe_scope cur_scope;
        return get_value(x); // Performs the check
    }
}
```

In order to make it nested I would add a reference counter like this:

```
/// RAII Type that toggles the flag on while it's alive
struct unsafe_scope
{
    thread_local static size_t ref_count;

    constexpr unsafe_scope()
    {
        unsafe_flag = true;
        ref_count++;
    }
    ~unsafe_scope()
    {
        ref_count--;
        if ( ref_count == 0 ) { unsafe_flag = false; }
    }
};

/// In source file
thread_local size_t unsafe_scope::ref_count = 0;
```

The ref_count doesn't need to be atomic since it's thread_local

Now I don't think there's a way to achieve the syntax you wanted with the `unsafe` before the scope, but if you put it right after the scope as such it should be about the same:

```
{ unsafe_scope cur_scope;
    return get_value(x); // Performs the check
}
```

Edit:

I've now noticed Quentin's answer is also a RAII type, just with slightly different semantics, instead of having a global thread_local flag a function just returns if the reference counter is bigger than 0. Also the macro achieves the exact syntax you wanted, although it's also possible with this `unsafe_scope` by modifying his macro like this:

```
#define unsafe\
    if (unsafe_scope cur_scope; false) {} else
```

His method uses C++17's if initializer, which lets you initiates a variable in the if statement, but the variable is still initialized in the else block, so it only gets destroyed after the else scope if over.